# whats the difference between the class files generated for a class with main function and the one without main function?

Tags: java

I am a beginner in java i want to know whats the difference between the class files created for a class with main function and the one created for a class without main function.we can create a class without a main function and able to compile it so whats the difference between the class files being generated.It may look like a stupid question but i just want to know the answer for this.

Thank you in advance

Comment: One `.class` file has a `main()` method, and one doesn't. Easy.

Comment: there are no other difference??is that so??

Comment: As far as I know, there's nothing special about the `main()` method that's visible in the `.class` file. It's just another method that happens to have special treatment.

Comment: In fact, you can have more than one class with a `static void main(String[] args)` method within a jar file; the manifest tells java which one is the entry point.

Comment: Or `java -cp "some/dir:." pkg.to.main.Class` to specify a specific `main` class on the command line.

Answer (score 4):

There is no special bytecode for one class with a `public static void main(String ..args)`, that method is compiled the same way as any other method.

The difference is made by the Java Virtual Machine (not the compiler), [whose specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html) states this:

> The Java Virtual Machine starts up by creating an initial class, which is specified in an implementation-dependent manner, using the bootstrap class loader (§5.3.1). The Java Virtual Machine then links the initial class, initializes it, **and invokes the public class method void main(String[])**.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in the compiler.

In the compiled bytecode are methods.

If there ist a

```
public static void main(String[] args){}
```

You will get a Class, which can be started by calling

```
java ClassName
```

It is just a convention, that the main-method is started, if called by Java.

**update**

Prior to Java 7 you could start a JavaClass like this (without a main-method):

```
//Don't use this
public class RunnableNoMain{
   static { new RunnableNoMain(); } //creates an instance.
}
```

The static initializer will create an instance and execute code. Right after, there will be a NoSuchMethodException (main ist not found)

Comment: Just a note, the last part of your answer (running a program without `main()`) no longer works for Java 7 and up.